# No debug output ColdFusion 2023

Tags: debugging, coldfusion

I have Coldfusion 2023 on Windows 11 Pro, and have turned on debugging in the CF admin. I am not seeing any debug output, although the test page specifically has cfsetting showdebugoutput="Yes", and my IP address is correctly entered in the CF Admin.  The pages are being served via the CF service on port 8500 (something I don't usually do -- in the past I've used IIS). I am out of ideas as to what is preventing debug output.  Any ideas?

cfsetting showdebugoutput="Yes".  There is no site-wide error handler (which was suggested elsewhere as a possible reason for no output).

Comment: This seems more of a configuration issue than a programming issue. Is this an existing application or just some test code? Is it using any framework like ColdBox or CFWheels? They may have settings that override what you're trying. Can you create a `test.cfm` and try just that page? Also, check the debugging options in CF Admin. I think the "classic" setting will show the debug info at the bottom of the page if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I am not using frameworks, and the simple test.cfm runs fine (just assign a value to a variable then print the variable. I added a cfdump of CGI scope to confirm the IP address was right. In short, CF is running fine, just no debug output is being appended to the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the CF Administrator, Debugging & Logging, start checking everything possible and try rerunning your test page. I've had the same issue before on a new install. Hopefully one of the checked boxes was the solution. Then go back and uncheck anything you don't need, but, my preference, is to see as much as possible locally so everything is checked except Flash Form, since Flash is no longer part of any of my projects.

Comment: This absolutely helped, thanks!  The only issue that remains is that the option for "report execution times", although checked, is not included. I normally have this as "Summary", but neither that nor "tree" view displays anything.  This is nice to have, but I can probably get by without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for local output only

```
<!--- add to the page header if you use one or within the application.cfc onRequest --->
 <cfset startTimer = GetTickCount()>
<--- add to the application.cfc onrequestend --->
<cfif cgi.remote_addr EQ "127.0.0.1">
<cfset endTimer = GetTickCount()> 
<cfset request.process_time = "#((endTimer-startTimer)*0.001)#" >
<p class="medium">
    <cfoutput>#request.process_time# seconds to complete</cfoutput>
</p>
</cfif>
```